# C# Outlook Plugin - Create new item into Sent Box without send that email

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm writing a plugin for outlook, I want to create new item into Sent Box but i don't want to send it, just save it to Sent Box.

Pls, help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook Object Model will not, generally, let you create a message in the sent state - `MailItem.Sent` property is read-only. Even on the MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), `MSGFLAG_UNSENT` bit can be removed from the `PR_MESSAGE_FLAGS` property only before the message is saved for the very first time. The only kind of item created by OOM in the sent state is a post item, so in theory, you can create a post item, save it, reset its `MessageClass` property to `"IPM.Note",` dereference it, reopen by the entry id - you will now have a MailItem in the sent state. You will not have to set all the sender and recipient properties (about a dozen of them) and remove post specific properties - take a look at a sent message with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage button).

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am also its author - any language) is an option, it can create a fake sent message easily:

```
Set MySession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
MySession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
Set Folder = MySession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
Set msg = Folder.Items.Add("IPM.Note")
msg.Sent = True
msg.Recipients.AddEx "The user", "user@domain.demo", "SMTP", olTo
msg.Sender = MySession.CurrentUser
msg.SentOnBehalfOf = MySession.CurrentUser
msg.subject = "Test sent message"
msg.Body = "test body"
msg.SentOn = Now
msg.ReceivedTime = Now
msg.Save
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed by use Redemption. But I have a new issue, I can't detect email in sent box is fake (created by redemption) or real?
can you help me?

Comment: You can set a custom property using RDOMial.Fields[] or RDOMail.UserProperties. Your can then check if that property is present to determine whether it was created by your code.